# How to find out what song is playing in the spotify app on the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios5, spotify

Is it possible to get info of the currently playing song in the Spotify app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, at the moment I don't believe that this functionality is possible. However, depending on the requirements of your application you could use Spotify's last.fm scrobbling to pick up the currently playing song from there instead.

Comment: Similarly, you might be able to get the data from https://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens as well. However, you will not know if it is the client on the iPhone playing or some other device.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that this not supported. Hopefully this will be possible at some point in the future.